# How to divide the value of a row if the number of digits is 13?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1 column as timestamp

```
UNIX Timestamp
1546357505
1546357518
1546357609412
1546357612
1546357761
```

I want to make all values as 10 digit number. So here only the value "1546357609412" needs to be divided by 1000. The final output should be

```
UNIX Timestamp
1546357505
1546357518
1546357609
1546357612
1546357761
```

I tried using the div function but then I'm not sure how to check if the value is 13 digit or not. Also, this column has 5 million values so I need an efficient way to make the change.

Comment: Please post the code you tried and the errors / problems you get.

Comment: I am using this but this divided all the values by 1000   df['UNIX Timestamp'] = df['UNIX Timestamp'].div(1000)

Comment: I want to make all numbers a ten digit number, you say. Do you mean just using the first 10 digits amd removing the other ones?

Comment: Why do you care how many digits there are? Why use only *10* digits? The values are Unix timestamps or they aren't. Perhaps your *real* question is how to detect which values are seconds and which *milliseconds*, and convert them to seconds? Instead of counting digits, just check which value is greater than eg 4000000000 and divide it by 1000. That should cover you until 2096

Comment: @Tom yes. I want to use just the first ten digits

Comment: @Panagiotis-kanavos yes you are right

Comment: @shreeja7 don't count digits then. Check which number is greater than 4000000000  (4*10^9) or 10^12 and divide by 1000. Counting the number of digits is *equivalent* to checking whether a number is greater than 10^12 after all. 4*10^9 in milliseconds is October 2 20196

Comment: @Panagiotis-kanavos I tried this but it again divided all values by 1000. Where am i going wrong?   df.loc[df['UNIX Timestamp '] > (4*10^9),'UNIX Timestamp']= df['UNIX Timestamp'].div(1000)

Comment: @shreeja7 that's what your code does - divide everything by 1000, then compare the result with the result of `df.loc[df['UNIX Timestamp '] > (4*10^9),'UNIX Timestamp']`

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. How will i get the final output? I am new to python.

Comment: Thanks i got your point. In python the power symbol is ** instead of ^. This where i was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could cast it as a `str` type and slice the first 10 digits only, then cast back as `int`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype(str).str[:10].astype(int)

0    1546357505
1    1546357518
2    1546357609
3    1546357612
4    1546357761
```